# openerp: how do I group my quotation/sales orders by products

Tags: odoo

I am currently using openerp v7 on Ubuntu.  I am trying to group my sales orders/quotations by products so I can analyse what my customers are requesting and I can order more of these products from my suppliers.

On my quotations page, I can group my quotations by customers but having troubel grouping them by products.

If anyone can help, please do...

Thanks in advance,

Victor

Comment: how do I go about this? Do I have to code it in python? Because I have tried to do it under the dashboard but to no luck

Comment: Easiest way to approach that would be a custom report, made in SQL and added into reporting tab - grouping by o2m fields is not possible via Odoo front-end.

Comment: how do I go about this, can you assist me with a step by step procedure?